# Process is eating all of the CPU time

Tags: process, freebsd

Is there any magic command to track down which process is starting this perl task that is eating 100% of CPU time? I have this problem on several machines where JBoss AS is installed.

[image]

Comment: Does freebsd know the `renice` command? You could at least make it run a bit slower.

Comment: With what uid is that process running? The same as apache?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `procstat` on FreeBSD.

```
procstat $PID
```

gives you the an overview of the process for example

```
 PID  PPID  PGID   SID  TSID THR LOGIN    WCHAN     EMUL          COMM        
8898  8894  1977  1977     0   6 tant     usem      FreeBSD ELF64 chrome
```

The PPID is the ID of the parrent process which might have started the process.

With

```
procstat -f $PID
```

you get the files opened by the `$PID`

```
procstat -c $PID
```

gives the arguments of that process.

The process looks suspicious. There is no `/usr/bin/javad` you should check if this process really opens this file or if the program has overwritten the first argument.

Comment: `procstat` says that this perl process (`PID 38181` in this example) `PPID` is `1` which is `/sbin/init`. `procstat -f` shows that none file is open by this process. `procstat -c` shows this argument: `/usr/bin/javad`.

Comment: @MarkZakred OK ether the program was started with as a background process or the starting process has finished. Could you give the whole out put of `procstat -c`?

Comment: @MarkZakred Also add the output of `procstat -f`.

Comment: Here you go: http://ideone.com/lq3EPw

Comment: Mhh this looks really fishy!

Comment: Also `procstat`: http://ideone.com/edizTc - and that is interesting: `ps -jp` shows user root, and `procstat` shows user (login) joefly.

Comment: I think that means that it was started via `sudo`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9714/discussion-between-raphael-ahrens-and-mark-zakred)

Answer (score 0):

You can see more information about the command by running

```
ps l 39181
```

This will show the command's arguments, which will usually include the name of the script that is being run.

If you wish to stay in `top`, you can press <kbd>f</kbd> and select the information fields that you would like to see. Look for the PPID. This is the ID of the process that spawned the perl process.

Comment: `ps l 39181` gives me `/usr/bin/javad (perl5.16.2)` and `ls -la /usr/bin/javad` says that `ls: /usr/bin/javad: No such file or directory`.

Comment: also, freebsd's top doesn't have `f` switch: http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=top&amp;sektion=1 I'd appreciate if you could point me to which one is equivalent to GNU's `f` in top. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkZakred mhhh there shoukld not be a `javad` in `/usr/bin/`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `ps -fp processid` to see the parent process. 
Use `ps -fjp pid` to see the progress group id and the group id will give you the hierarchy of processes.

Edit: As noted by comments below (and I don't have comment privileges yet), this only works in Linux.

Comment: The FreeBSD version of `ps` has a different interpretation of `-f` here the man page entry: "Show commandline and environment information about swapped out processes.  This option is honored only if the UID of the user is 0."

Comment: `ps -jp`: http://ideone.com/MpyIid

Answer (score 0):

**top** is the beautiful command which will list all the processes running, % of CPU utilization, % of memory utilization along with all other important information.